# Vertices with complex values in Apache Giraph

Tags: hadoop, graph, giraph

I am trying to read some text file containing relevant vertices information into Giraph: each line is

**vertex_id attribute_1 attribute_2 .....attribute_n**

where each attribute is a string.

The goal would be to create a vertex where all these attributes are part of vertex's value.

Looking up the various input formats I could not find anything out of the box, so I assume I have to derive my vertex input class  from **VertexValueInputFormat** (I have a separate reader for edges).

Problem is: how? I have created a a Value class which contains a String[] array, but how do I hand it over to Giraph/Hadoop? Here  is a reader for a single line:

https://giraph.apache.org/giraph-core/apidocs/org/apache/giraph/io/formats/TextVertexValueInputFormat.TextVertexValueReaderFromEachLine.html

**protected abstract V  getValue(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text line)**

The thought was, V will be an **ArrayWritable**, but does not seem to like it.

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your vertex has a custom value (in your case array of string), then you need to have a custom vertex value class and a custom vertex input format. 
As an example, take a look at a very simple custom vertex class. This class has a `double` value, an `int`, and a `long`  : https://gist.github.com/sar-vivek/df09cca17cc3f6b5ac60 
note - you must override `readFields()` and `write()` accordingly.

Then you need to have a custom vertex input format. For above vertex class, I have modified the in-built json vertex reader a little bit. Here is the example - https://gist.github.com/sar-vivek/f39edacec6d9a43c3717 [notice how the value of a vertex is set on line 68].

Comment: the links which you have provided are not accessible anymore, please update the answer with new link, and also please avoid answering via links

Comment: @sarvivek could you update your answer with actual code & no links?