# Array vertex values for Apache Giraph

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I need to process a graph which has arrays (double) for their vertex value rather than a single double. So the input format would be vertex_Id(string)\t vertex_value (array)\t neighbors. Looking at the documentation, it seems that there is no class that supports such a format. What options do I have to feed the input which this format to Giraph?

Answer (score 0):

You should adapt one Input Format or write your own. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712589/giraph-bests-vertex-input-format-for-an-input-file-with-ids-of-type-string) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800957/vertices-with-complex-values-in-apache-giraph?rq=1) for example. You should think in using separators that can't be part of the elements of your graph, with the idea that having this will facilitate the job of parsing lines of your input file through your input format.